# Shell script: count the copies of each line from a txt

Tags: shell, unix, compare, line

I would like to count the copies of each line in a txt file and I have tried so many things until know, but none worked well. In my case the text has just a word in each line.

This was my last try

```
echo -n 'enter file for edit: '
read file
for line in $file ; do
echo  'grep -w $line $file'
done; <$file
```

For example:

input file

```
a
a
a
c
c
```

Output file

```
a 3
c 2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thnx!!! that worked but not copletely!! it misses the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sort < $file | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 " " $1}'
```

Comment: @user1866935, including a broken caps lock key? ;)